# How do you make a generator release a value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently I am trying to make a binomial coefficient using Python. So I tried to create 3 different generators, one for n!, k! and (n-k)!. Since I know return will not give back a value but instead a location of where the memory is stored, I tried to use yield. But if i put yield as below, it somehow gave another memory being stored rather than dividing each other in the ans formula. I'm still confused because I assume it is my indentation but as I fiddle with it, it just keep giving error messages. Can anyone help to modify this such that it releases a value? I just want to make the generator spit out values so that they can be used for the ans formula in the last line.

```
def binom_coeff(n,k):
    def fact(n):
        basic = 1
        for i in range(1,n+1):
            basic = basic * i
    yield basic

    def fact(k):
        basic_3 = 1
        for j in range(1,j+1):
            basic_3 = basic_3 * j
    yield basic_3

    def fact_d(n,k):
        basic_2 = 1
        for m in range(1, n-k+1):
            basic_2 = basic_2 * m
    yield basic_2
        
    ans = basic / (basic_3 * basic_2)

    return ans
```

Comment: You seem to be defining several functions that you never call. What's the idea behind that?

Comment: I don't think you want a generator here. Just `return basic`, etc. And those statements should be inside the functions. Currently, the `yield` statements are not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want a generator here. Just `return basic`, etc. And those statements should be inside the functions. Currently, the `yield` statements are not.

Even if you did want to use a generator, you never call the functions. Also, there are a few typos.

```
def binom_coeff(n,k):
    def fact(n):
        basic = 1
        for i in range(1, n+1):
            basic = basic * i
        return basic

    ans = fact(n) / (fact(k) * fact(n-k))
    return ans
```